# Tab layout in landscape

Tags: android, tabs, landscape

I don't know if this is a silly question, but here is a screen shot first in my emulator.

[image]

As what I have seen in an Iphone implementation, the tabs adjust their size so that all the tabs will occupy the entire space. My question is, can I implement it also in android? Like the tabs have the same sizes and the last tab is not bigger than the others? If it is possible, how? Or is it the default behavior on android? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this [Navigation Tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

Comment: if you look closely, I already did that, and also on the link, the image displayed is the same from what I provided.